# Android: Dynamically adding new row to grid view

Tags: android, android-layout

Im trying to fill up this GridView, with a cell that I created in a separate xml

GridView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF2C3C63"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="11dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="195dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="kamuScan"
        android:text="temp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ScanningDone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Complete"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.941">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/inputGridView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="269dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:columnWidth="200dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            android:numColumns="1">

        </GridView>
    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Single cell:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/barcodeTextView"
        android:layout_width="146dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Barcode"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/IncrementDown"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:text="-">
    </Button>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Quantity"
        android:layout_width="51dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/IncrementUp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:text="+">
    </Button>



</LinearLayout>
```

The class for the adapter:

```
public class InputUIGenerator extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mContext;

    public InputUIGenerator(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View inputGridView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        inputGridView = new View(mContext);
        inputGridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.input_grid_single, null);

        TextView textView = (TextView)       inputGridView.findViewById(R.id.barcodeTextView);
        Button incrementUp = (Button) inputGridView.findViewById(R.id.IncrementUp);
        Button incrementDown = (Button) inputGridView.findViewById(R.id.IncrementDown);
        EditText quantity = (EditText) inputGridView.findViewById(R.id.Quantity);
        return inputGridView;
    }
}
```

And the class where everything should be displayed:

```
public class InputPage extends Activity {
    GridView inputGridView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.input_page);

        InputUIGenerator generatorAdapter = new InputUIGenerator(this);
        inputGridView=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.inputGridView);
        inputGridView.setAdapter(generatorAdapter);
        inputGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
                
            }
        });
```

This creates one single row with the TextView, Button, TextEdit, Button which is good.
The event to create a new line should be from a barcode scanner, to replace that, i've added a button for now.
So the desired outcome would be to press the button, and get a new row, and keep the values of the first one.
This may be the wrong approach, Im really not sure at this point, how I should be doing this.

Also on a separate note, at the end, I'd like to collect the data from all of these items inside the single cell, and I don't really know how to dynamically assign IDs to them while they are being generated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've found [this](https://github.com/droidcodes/DynamicViews) code on github, and I managed to implement it the way I want to.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).